# Vue Router - Overcome next({}) Uncaught (in promise) undefined error

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm randomly receiving an error in regards to using `next({ path: 'dfdfd' })`.

The error is `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` which I believe is stopping the rest of my script from running.

I have tried all options from the web but all are in reference to using `$router.push` not `next()`.

```js
next({path: '/profile'}, () => {});
next({path: '/profile'}).catch(()=> {});
try { next({path: '/profile'}) } catch(err){}
```

Dont do anything.

Can anyone tell me how I catch this error?

Regards

Edit.

The above is used in the error handling of an axios request which is called from vue-routers `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteUpdate` methods.

```js
/**
 * Error Handler
 * @param error
 * @param next
 * @param to
 * @param from
 */
errorHandler(error, next, to, from) {
    switch(error.response.status) {
        case 401:
            if(from.path !== '/login') {
                next({path: '/login'});
            } else {
                next();
            }
        break;
        case 498:
            for(let i in error.response.data.errors) {
                db.commit('setNotifications', []);
                db.commit('addErrorNotification', error.response.data.errors[i][0]);
            }
            if(from.path !== '/profile') {
                next({path: '/profile'}); // where the error is thrown
            } else {
                next();
            }
        break;
        default:
            next();
        break;
    }
    db.commit('setPageLoading', false);
}
```

Comment: `next` fn is provided by lifecycles provided by `vue-router`, can you add some more code to help get a better overview

Comment: @ShivamSingh I've added a comment which should help.

Comment: Apparently there is no convenient way to handle errors arising from the `next()` calls as they always return `void` and do not throw.
Maybe try: `router.onError(callback)`. I'm not sure if it'll really be called for issues during a `next()` execution. See details: https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-onerror